# What armor is Scoresby referring to?

Tags: avatar-the-way-of-water

In *Avatar The Way of Water* (2022), the Sky People shot a mother Tulkun with a tracker. Two submarines were
released underwater and are heading towards her:

> PILOT 1: Target in sight. 3-6 is in hot with harpoons.
>
> GUNNER 1: Here we go, baby.

The scene then cuts to Scoresby, the captain, who is talking to Miles’
avatar on a ship equipped with a explosive tipped harpoon. Scoresby
aims the harpoon towards the mother Tulkun:

> Scoresby: See, we go in from below where there's gaps in **the armor**.

The scene then cuts back to the submarine crew:

> GUNNER 1: All right, let's go. Get up in there.

What armor is Scoresby referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tulkun are armor-plated, according to the film's official 'pandorapedia'

> Of all the marine fauna inhabiting the Metkayina reef, only the
> enormous, highly-intelligent, sea-dwelling tulkun are truly sentient.
> In fact, the tulkun possess their own names and a rich family history
> and culture as well as sophisticated music and poetry. Eons ago, the
> tulkun engaged in long stretches of bloody warfare that spanned
> generations. Eventually, the tulkun changed their ways and
> collectively swore to a life of absolute pacifism. **With their thick
> armor plating shielding them from aggressors, tulkun have no need for
> violent retaliation.**
>
> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>https://www.avatar.com/pandorapedia/tulkun</sup></sub>